# How to make DE0-nano use ttl-232R-3V3 cable communication with PC by 1 bit(with clash-lang)?

Tags: intel-fpga, clash

I am trying to use the Altera DE0-nano to communication with the PC. I am using the ttl-232R-3v3 cable, currently it transmit 8 bits data once, but with the cable, it can be 1 bit a time transmit. How do I do it?

I have finish the 8 bit code:

```
type ST = BitVector 28

example :: ( ST , ST ) -> BitVector 8 -> (( ST , ST ) , BitVector 8)
example ( cntr1 , cntr2 ) input = ((cntr1’,cntr2’) , out)
  where
  sec_5 = 250000000
  ascii_Y = 0x59 --ASCII for "Y" yes
  ascii_N = 0x4E --ASCII for "N" no

  cntr1’ | cntr1 >= sec_5 = 0  --At 50 MHz : 5 seconds
         | otherwise = cntr1 + 1
  cntr2’ = cntr2
  out | input == maxBound = ascii_Y
      | otherwise = ascii_Y
```

Here is the output:

[image: exampleOutput]

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking (question could use a LOT of improvements in the editing department), but you might find my [serial transmitter](https://github.com/gergoerdi/clash-utils/blob/master/src/Cactus/Clash/SerialTX.hs) CLaSH implementation useful.